# gcloud app deploy fails for my nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy my little express static app to google cloud. It is failing however I cannot figure out why. There is nothing in the logs. I have deployed by adding the verbosity to debug flag. I have found this json being sent to google app engine

```
  "betaSettings": {
    "module_yaml_path": "app.yaml",
    "vm_runtime": "nodejs"
  },
  "env": "flex",
  "handlers": [
    {
      "script": {
        "scriptPath": "PLACEHOLDER"
      },
      "urlRegex": ".*"
    }
  ],
  "runtime": "vm"
}"
```

The thing that bothers me is that the scriptpath is resolved as placeholder. Not sure if it makes sense. Here's my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

My app.js is as follows

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080))
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.listen(app.get('port'))
```

I have a public folder which I assume is being deployed but cannot verify. Any suggestions?

Comment: it *might* help to show *exactly* how you're deploying and how is it failing.

Comment: I think the problem is it was not uploading the public folder inside the node project. I looked up and told me to use gsutil to load static source so tried that and it worked. Though I am a still pissed that it took me 5 mins to deploy on heroku and 3 hours of research to deploy on gcp.

Comment: Deployment was done "gcloud app deploy". Have renamed my express.js to app.js and added the port setting but none worked.. When I displayed the --verbosity=info, it looked like node_modules directory was skipped which it should so not sure why the static public folder never got loaded.I did a sudo inside the app-engine instance and didnot see any public folder but found the app.js mounted. My next choice will probably be writing a docker image and uploading it through kubernetes but for now I am happy since I am using google cloud storage 'gsutil' and the sync even though... not instant is goo

Comment: Should I give the instructions for google web page to use google cloud storage for express static as an answer?

Comment: If that solved your problem - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply never worked for me. My options was to create a docker. Later on I decided to google for answers. The answer was to use a constant google cloud storage and deploy the output using gsutil. It works, I am not too happy that the express static does not work for me. The link that explains how to deploy for express static [Best practice works for me not express static](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files) I tried deploying nodejs on heroku. Deployed perfectly in 5 minutes. Wish google was as simple.